# Function parameter for output in Perl

Tags: perl

I wanted to remove white spaces from multiple datafiles through the `for` loop below. I inserted the `for` loop inside a function. The function can read the input data files, but the output files print doesn't work correctly unless I reset the variable (`$new_data`) after every time it prints to a file. Otherwise, the earlier data gets appended to the later data. Also, is there any problem if the same files as the input and output since I have no use of the input file later?

**Pass @row for reading from inputFile and  $new_data for writing to the outputFile**

```
$dir = '/****/';

$inputFileSpring = $dir . "SpringSIMS.dat";
$inputFileSummer = $dir . "SummerSIMS.dat";
$inputFileFall = $dir . "FallSIMS.dat";

$outputFileSpring = $dir . "Spring.dat";
$outputFileSummer = $dir . "Summer.dat";
$outputFileFall = $dir . "Fall.dat";

#Read Spring SIMS Data
open (NOTE, "$inputFileSpring" || die "Could not open $inputFileSpring\n");
processFile(@row=<NOTE>);
close(NOTE);

#Write Spring Data
open(NOTE, ">$outputFileSpring" || die "Could not open $inputFileSpring\n");
print NOTE $new_data;
close(NOTE);
reset('new_data');

#Read Summer SIMS Data
open (NOTE, "$inputFileSummer" || die "Could not open $inputFileSummer\n");
processFile(@row=<NOTE>);
close(NOTE);

#Write Summer Data
open(NOTE, ">$outputFileSummer" || die "Could not open $inputFileSummer\n");
print NOTE $new_data;
close(NOTE);
reset('new_data');

#Read Fall SIMS Data
open (NOTE, "$inputFileFall" || die "Could not open $inputFileFall\n");
processFile(@row=<NOTE>);
close(NOTE);

#Write Fall Data
open(NOTE, ">$outputFileFall" || die "Could not open $inputFileFall\n");
print NOTE $new_data;
close(NOTE);
reset('new_data');


sub processFile
{
    for $row(@row) {
        chop($row);
        @field = split(/\|/, $row);
        for ($i=0; $i<@field; $i++) {
            if ($field[$i] =~ /^ /)
            {
                $field[$i] = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                $field[$i] =~ s/ *$//g;
            }
            $new_data .= $field[$i] . "|";
        }
        $lastchar = chop($new_data);
        if (@field == 15) {
            $new_data .= "|0";
        }
        $new_data .= "\n";
    }
    # return $new_data;
} # END  sub processFile

exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Wowzers. Well, your *main* problem is that you're using global variables. As a general rule, you should only resort to global variables when... well, never, really. And certainly not in simple cases like this.

If you use a lexical scope on your variables, and pass arguments to the subroutines, you will never notice issues like this. E.g.:

```
my $foo = process($bar);

sub process {
    my $arg = shift;
    my $value = ....;
    return $value;
}
```

Now, I can't help but notice that in each case you perform the exact same `open`, so why not include that into your subroutine. As a benefit, you don't need to worry about closing file handles, as they are closed automatically when they go out of scope.

Not sure what your `$last_char` variable is for, so I left it as a lexical. I've also done nothing about the code in your subroutine, except fix the atrocious indentation. Notable changes in your code:

- Using `strict` and `warnings`!
- Use a return value, returning the value of a lexically scoped variable
- Passing arguments to subroutines
- `chop` -> `chomp`. You basically should never use `chop`.
- Using a basename list to build file names instead of repeating similar names
- Using three argument `open`, with explicit mode and a lexical file handle.

**Note:** You should *never, ever* write perl code without using `use strict; use warnings;`. There is no benefit from not using them: You'll only spend more time trying to find simple errors.

**Note#2:** Untested code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @seasons = ("Spring", "Summer", "Fall");

for my $season (@seasons) {
    my $input  = $season . "SIMS.dat";
    my $output = $season . ".dat";
    output_data($input, $output);
}

sub processFile {
     my $file = shift;
     open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
     while (my $row = <$fh>) {
         chomp $row;  # NOTE: never use chop, use chomp instead
         my @field = split(/\|/, $row);
         for (my $i=0; $i<@field; $i++){
             if ($field[$i] =~ /^ /) {
                 $field[$i] = " ";
             } else {
                 $field[$i] =~ s/ *$//g;
             }
         }
         my $new_data = join "|", @field;
         if(@field == 15) {
             $new_data .= "|0";
         }
         $new_data .= "\n";
     }
     return $new_data;
}

sub output_data {
    my ($input, $output) = @_;
    open my $fh, '>', $output or die "$output: $!";
    print $fh processFile($input);
}
```

---

**ETA:** Looking at your subroutine code now, the following optimizations occur to me:

```
$new_data .= $field[$i] . "|";
....
my $lastchar = chop($new_data);
```

No. Instead use `join`:

```
$new_data = join "|", @field;
```

This part:

```
 if ($field[$i] =~ /^ /) {
     $field[$i] = " ";
 } else {
     $field[$i] =~ s/ *$//g;
 }
```

...will *either* change the first field to a single space `" "`, if the first character is a space, *or* it will strip spaces from the end of the string. Is this *really* what you want? I.e. `"  foo"` will be changed to `" "` (space).

I would imagine you're after something like:

```
$field[$i] =~ s/^ *//;
$field[$i] =~ s/ *$//;
```

In which case you can simply do:

```
for (@field) {
    s/^ *//;
    s/ *$//;
}
```

Which works as intended because `$_` is aliased to each element in the array, and they will be altered by the substitution regex. A more verbose solution:

```
for my $value (@field) {
    $value =~ s/^ *//;
    $value =~ s/ *$//;
}
```

Or, better yet, you can include this in your `split` statement:

```
my $new_data = join "|", split /\s*\|\s*/, $row;
$new_data =~ s/^ *//;
$new_data =~ s/ *$//;
```

Or use a regex, which will probably be less expensive:

```
$row =~ s/\s*\|\s*/|/g;
$row =~ s/^ *//;
$row =~ s/ *$//;
my $new_data = $row;
```

Comment: @zaman Ah yes, it needs to be declared at the start of the sub. Oh well, I guess you solved it. Good thing you had `strict` and `warnings` turned on eh? Otherwise, you would not have caught the mistake that I made. ;) This actually makes for an excellent example of why one should always use strict and warnings.

Comment: TLP thanks so much for your optimal solution and detailed explanation. I ran your modified version with little twick on $new_data since it was complaining for "Global symbol "$new_data" requires explicit package name at testTally.pl line 34." therefore, i declared it at the beginning as   `my $new_data = "";`  Now the problem is when I run the program it only writes the last line of the input line to the output file meaning a single line entry. Do you have any clue why it might be behaving that way? Thanks again.

Comment: TLP when I run the program it only writes the last line of the input line to the output file meaning a single line entry. Do you have any clue why it might be behaving that way? Thanks again.

Comment: @zaman You put the declaration in the wrong place. Put `my $new_data;` right below `my $file = shift;`.

Comment: TLP thannks again for your response. That didn't resolve the issue. if you want i can post some sample data. Also, what does **shift** do? i tried to understad from the google but didn't quite get it.

Comment: Ah, you need to use `.=` instead, not `=`. `shift` removes the first argument of an array and returns it. Inside a sub, if no array is supplied, it shifts the `@_` array, which contains the sub arguments.

Comment: i did use `my $new_data .= "";` but still same.

Comment: is there anyway i can debug to figure out where is the problem?

Comment: here is a sample data incase if you have any clue

Comment: _input:_  
  CAN|D|FRO  |2000S|28S  |2059 |SEEK FRESH SEMIN. II|                    |00.0|03.0|00.0|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|201202

_output:_  
  CAN|D|FRO|2000S|28S|2059|SEEK FRESH SEMIN. II| |00.0|03.0|00.0|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|201202

Comment: basically remove the empty spaces between |

Comment: @zaman I can clean that up with `s/\s*\|\s*/|/g`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the $new_data variable as a global variable, and all your assignments are append assignments, this causes your data to build up without clearing it.

So to deal with this without calling reset every time, you can put the clearing inside the subroutine, so every time you call the subroutine, it will clear it automatically.

```
sub processFile 
 {
  $new_data = ""; #this should empty it out
for $row(@row) {
        chop($row);
        @field = split(/\|/, $row);
        for ($i=0; $i<@field; $i++){
            if ($field[$i] =~ /^ /) 
             {
                 $field[$i] = " ";
             }            
            else 
             {
                $field[$i] =~ s/ *$//g;
             }
            $new_data .= $field[$i] . "|";
        }
        $lastchar = chop($new_data);
        if(@field == 15) {
                $new_data .= "|0";
        }
        $new_data .= "\n";
}
# return $new_data;
} # END  sub processFile
```

This way, it should clear it whenever you run the function, so you won't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of Perl's `reset` function is archaic, but your use is also incorrect. If you want to erase the contents of `$new_data`, just say one of

```
$new_data = '';
$new_data = undef;
undef $new_data;
```

What  `reset('new_data')` actually does is delete ALL symbols(*) that begin with the letters 'a','d','e','n','t','w', or '_'.

(*) - it wouldn't delete lexical variables, but this script doesn't have any of those.

Comment: ...or, more correctly, just say "Don't use reset() when lexical variables are such a superior solution in every way possible".